# Closed Won status is not available is opportunity

Tags: opportunity, fields

I am not able to see the *Closed Won* in the list of Stage in opportunity.

[image: enter image desan cription here]

*Closed Won* is active field.

[image]

Where should I look for the solution to this stage?

Comment: Do you have any record type on Opportunity?

Comment: Yes.
These are Prepaid and Broadband.

Answer (score 2):

As you have two Records type available Opportunity. So make sure you have added Closed Won in both record Type and it will be available.

Please make sure to check Sales process as well and if missing add that value there.

Here is a trailhead module for your reference.

[Create a Sales Process and Use Opportunities](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/admin_intro_opptys_leads/units/admin_intro_opptys_leads_opportunities)

Comment: IT will be in the Sales Process, not specifically the Record Type. The Record Type uses a specific Sales Process, but going to the Record Type will not specifically solve the problem.